# Find the node which a shape belongs to using cordinates

Tags: game-physics, godot, gdscript

I'm currently in doubt if I can use coordinates(X,Y) to find if there is an shape in said coordinate, and if there is I would get/find the node which the coordinate is in belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find what `PhysicsBody2D`s (`StaticBody2D`, `RigidBody2D`, `KinematicBody2D`) are at a given position, you can use a `RayCast2D` of length 0, placed at that position.

Or, you can use a [`Physics2DDirectSpaceState`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html) in a similar fashion as the `RayCast2D` would do behind the scenes…

Or better yet, use [`intersect_point`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html#class-physics2ddirectspacestate-method-intersect-point):

```
var position:Vector2 = whatever_position_you_want_to_query()

var world:World2D = get_world_2d()
var space_state:Physics2DDirectSpaceState = world.direct_space_state
var collisions:Array = space_state.intersect_point(position)
for collision in collisions:
    var body:PhysicsBody2D = collision["collider"]
    print(body)
```

Or a shorter (with less explicit type information) version:

```
var position:Vector2 = whatever_position_you_want_to_query()

for collision in get_world_2d().direct_space_state.intersect_point(position):
    print(collision["collider"])
```

Note that the function [`get_world_2d`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_canvasitem.html#class-canvasitem-method-get-world-2d) is defined in `CanvasItem` and thus available in any derived types (`Node2D`, `Control`).

Comment: This was spot on! Once again, thank you for the detailed explanation.